# SharePoint: Someone leaves the organization but must remain in list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, sharepoint-list

We have a list of people.  In that list is a "Person or Group" column that validates the person against Active Directory (AD).  Since someone recently left our organization he is now inactive in AD.  As a result when maintaining his SharePoint list record, his name no longer validates and in order to save the record we have to remove his AD username.  We now have a record which is no longer tied to the person.

Sure.  We could create the name field as basic text, but management doesn't like that entering text is not aided by AD validation.

Is there a way of getting the best of both worlds?

We don't want AD forcing us to detach former employee user accounts from our SharePoint lists since those employee records serve historic purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've seen this work is to leave the person active in AD but put them in a special group that is denied permission to login.  That way they still have an active record for SharePoint to reference but it can't be used to connect to your domain.

Comment: Unfortunately, we were told by upper management that Microsoft urges old AD accounts to be deleted.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121941/sharepoint-are-ad-bound-person-columns-impractical-for-common-use.

Comment: @Mario - Did you ever find an answer to this? I believe SharePoint uses AD when searching for a user, but only uses the UIL for historical purposes (someone was selected last year, left the company and that record hasn’t been touched yet) - Is that correct?

Comment: No.  In instances where it gave us problems we created a Users lists (a standard SharePoint list) and use that list as a lookup.  It's okay if that list has a link to the People Picker since you are not relying on it.